# Where is the Saarland-Ticket valid?

Tags: trains, germany

I'm trying to book a train ticket on from Saarbrücken to Bonn. If I try searching "nur Nahverkehr", bahn.de suggests the "Saarland-Ticket". It seems like this might be valid in the Rhineland-Palatinate as well, and from there I guess some nearby cities, but I can't find a description of exactly where it is valid.

What area is covered by Deutsche Bahn's "Saarland-Ticket"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [a PDF on bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de/regional/view/mdb/pv/deutschland_erleben/allgemein/tickets/pdfs_laender-tickets/2013/mdb_98004_rhl_pfalz_saarl_ticket_geltbereich_ab091212.pdf) the Saarland- and Rheinland-Pfalz-Ticket have the same validity: practically all regional routes inside the Saarland and Rhineland-Palatinate, as well as a few into neighbouring states. The PDF lists all routes where the ticket is valid.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [DB website](http://www.bahn.de/regional/view/regionen/saar/freizeit/saar_ticket.shtml?dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0014_lt-saar_LZ01), the Saarland-ticket is valid in:

> Alle Nahverkehrszüge, Verkehrsverbünde sowie fast alle Linienbusse im Saarland und in Rheinland-Pfalz

So all local trains, metropolitan public transport and most buses in Saarland and  Rhineland-Palatinate. Conversely, the Rheinland-Pfalz-Ticket is also valid in Saarland.

Comment: I guessed as much. The part that I was confused about (and isn't mentioned on the description of the ticket) is that it is also valid for some cities near the border of Rhineland-Palatine, including Bonn.